# Calculating how many sub directories and files in 'documents/'

Tags: linux, command

I'm learning Linux through a gameshell.

Like the title says; I need to find the amount of sub directories and files in 'documents/'. The command runs fine but its the not the right answer. Here's my command :

```
find documents/ -type f | wc -l | awk '{print $1}'
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Be aware that `wc -l` counts *lines* not *files* (filenames may contain newlines)

Comment: I assumed it would count the lines in the files, thats why i used wc -l. Is there a better suited command ?

Comment: If you want to count *lines in the files* that's a whole different thing

Comment: it wouldn't be the equivalent in a certain way ? display all the lines in the files = the amount of sub directories ?

Answer (score 2):

Including `-type f` means it only covers files, and not directories.  Try removing this part and see if works better.

And you might want to try removing `| awk '{ print $1 }'` to see if that part is truly necessary.

Comment: That would also make it find symbolic links etc. and would still mis-count files with embedded newlines.

Comment: Very true, although I doubt the gameshell referenced is digging that deep.

Answer (score 2):

Your command only counts the number of lines outputted from `find`.  The `find` command will only output the pathnames of regular files in or under the `documents` directory.

If you want to count the number of regular files and directories in or under your `documents` directory you may do this in the `zsh` shell:

```sh
set -- documents/**/*(DN/) documents/**/*(DN.)
printf 'There are %d regular files and directories in or under "documents"\n' "$#"
```

This sets the *positional parameters* (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) to the result of expanding the two filenames globbing patterns `documents/**/*(DN/)` and  `documents/**/*(DN.)`, the first of which will match all regular files while the second matches directories (no matter if they are hidden or not).  The `**` pattern matches "recursively" down into subdirectories.

Once the positional parameters have been set, the special variable `$#` will hold the number of these parameters.

In the `bash` shell, which does not support the *glob qualifiers* `(DN/)` and `(DN.)`, you may use a loop:

```bash
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob

count=0
for pathname in documents/**/*; do
    if [[ -f $pathname ]] || [[ -d $pathname ]]; then
       [[ ! -h $pathname ]] && count=$(( count + 1 ))
    fi
done

printf 'There are %d regular files and directories in or under "documents"\n' "$count"
```

This is slightly more involved than the `zsh` variation, but should be easy to follow.  We first set a number of shell options so that we can use `**`, so that we count hidden names, and so that the pattern resolves to nothing if there are no matches (these last two equates to the `D` and the `N` in the `zsh` glob qualifier).

Inside the loop, we test whether the current pathname is a regular file or a directory, and not a symbolic link.  If it's a regular file or directory, we count it.

In `sh`, you have to resort to `find`:

```sh
find documents \( -type f -o -type d \) -exec echo . \; | wc -l
```

We look for regular files or directories in or under `documents`, and for each such thing we output a dot on a line by itself.  The `wc -l` then counts the number of lines produced.  This avoids counting filenames with embedded newlines multiple times.

Note that this variation will also count the `documents` directory itself.

Comment: Yes, I'm required to use find. Also how come when I try to find the amount of files and sub directories separately, it doesn't add up to the same total compared to 

( -type f -o -type d ) .

Comment: @ForzaTekk I can't make the `find` command count regular files and directories separately in such a way that the sum is different from what I'm getting when I do both at once.  How much do your sums differ?

Comment: it differs by 4 ! I did them separately and came up with the good answer. But if I wanted to do both command in one it doesn't come up with the good answer.

Comment: @ForzaTekk Well, assuming you are using the _exact_ command I gave, there should be no difference. I can unfortunately not see what's happening on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to deal with files names that may contain spaces, newlines or **anything** is to convert each filename to a single safe character (like `X`).

With find we can execute a command for each file/directory found:

```
find documents/ -type f -exec printf X \; ; echo
```

That will generate an string with as many `X` as there are files (change `f` to `d` to count directories). To convert that to a number, we can capture the result of the command and print the size of the resulting string:

```
$ str="$(find documents -type d -exec printf X \;)"
$ echo "${#str}"
23
```

Or directly count bytes (equal to characters as the only character used is `X`):

```
$ find testit -type d -exec printf X \; | wc -c
```

The command find counts dot-files and could follow symlinks (with -L) or not (by default). If avoiding dot-files and following symbolic links (to files, not to directories since bash 4.3) by default is not a problem, we can use **globbing**

```
$ ( shopt -s globstar; set -- documents/**/*/; echo "$#" )
23
```

For directories, and:

```
$ ( shopt -s globstar; set -- documents/**/*; echo "$#" )
65
```

For all files **and** directories (not following directory symlinks).